# Lucene what i can replace iterator in metod?

Tags: java, lucene

I have an idea:

1. looking for a pattern in the text,
2. if I found a pattern, then I want to take its position from the text.

Now i have 1.

Part 2 done, but it use iterator, it's this means that we will go through all terms before we get to the template I need, how can i get my term right away and possition ones of text?

My code:

```
public void methodFromStack() throws Exception {
        
    Directory directory = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, indexWriterConfig);

    Document doc = new Document();
    // Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES
    FieldType type = new FieldType();
    type.setStoreTermVectors(true);
    type.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);
    type.setStoreTermVectorOffsets(true);
    type.setStored(true);
    type.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
    Field fieldStore = new Field("tags", "Kite good world.", type);
    doc.add(fieldStore);
    writer.addDocument(doc);
    writer.close();
    
    DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    
    //Поиск по словосочетанию с учетом отступа
    QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("tags", new StandardAnalyzer());
    Query query = queryParser.parse("\"Kite World\"~1");
    TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, 1);
    
    for ( ScoreDoc scoreDoc : results.scoreDocs) {

        Fields termVs = reader.getTermVectors(scoreDoc.doc);
        Terms f = termVs.terms("tags");

        TermsEnum te = f.iterator();
        PostingsEnum docsAndPosEnum = null;
        BytesRef bytesRef;

        //Here iterator, output all terms, but i need get one my result term and possition
        while ((bytesRef = te.next()) != null) {
            docsAndPosEnum = te.postings(docsAndPosEnum, PostingsEnum.ALL);
            // for each term (iterator next) in this field (field)
            // iterate over the docs (should only be one)
            int nextDoc = docsAndPosEnum.nextDoc();
            assert nextDoc != DocIdSetIterator.NO_MORE_DOCS;
            final int fr = docsAndPosEnum.freq();
            final int p = docsAndPosEnum.nextPosition();
            final int o = docsAndPosEnum.startOffset();
            
            System.out.println("Word: " + bytesRef.utf8ToString());
            System.out.println("Position: "+ p + ", startOffset: " + o + " length: " 
 +bytesRef.length + " Freg: " + fr);
        
            if(fr > 1){
                for(int iter = 1; iter <= fr-1; iter++) {
                    System.out.println("Possition: "+ docsAndPosEnum.nextPosition());
                }
          
            }


        }
    }
}
```

(I know that in the old version of the library Lucene there were class TermFreqVector and class TermPositionVector?, but then with the transition to the new version from 3 to 4 there were changes. After these changes, all I found was the adoption of an iterator.

Use: Windows+NetBeans+maven+Lucene 7.4.0)

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve the problem: use the method **seekExact** and you can use that code to test:

```
        TermsEnum te = f.iterator();
        PostingsEnum docsAndPosEnum = null;
        if (te.seekExact(ref)) { 
            
            docsAndPosEnum = te.postings(docsAndPosEnum, PostingsEnum.ALL);
            int nextDoc = docsAndPosEnum.nextDoc();
            assert nextDoc != DocIdSetIterator.NO_MORE_DOCS;
            final int freg = docsAndPosEnum.freq();
            final int pos = docsAndPosEnum.nextPosition();
            final int o = docsAndPosEnum.startOffset();

            System.out.println("Word: " + ref.utf8ToString());
            System.out.println("Position: " + pos + ", startOffset: " + o + " length: " + ref.length + " Freg: " + freg);
```